# How do you extract the contents of specific cell (row,column) of a Microsoft Excel document that spans over 1000 "Sheets"?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document that contains over 1000 "sheets" of contact information of people (one person per sheet).

Row 8 and Column C contain a person's home address on each of the 1000+ sheets.

How can I extract (Row 8, Col C) for each 1000+ sheets without manually copying/pasting them from each sheet?

In the end I would like to have all home addresses pasted into a MS Word document which can be printed out on special printable address label paper.

Are there scripts out there that will do this? is it simple to write one? Would appreciate all / any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Where does a database factor into this question? Have you considered automating Excel to extract them (via VBA, VBScript, C#, VB.NET, or any other language capable of OLE automation)? How about a relatively simple Excel macro that iterates through the sheets and copies the cell content and puts it into the proper place on a new sheet? Or a Word macro that does the same and creates the Word document? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Ken - removed database tag.  My first time writing code using Microsoft APIs, wasn't sure if there was an SQL-like feature in excel where we could do "SELECT ROW(8),COL(C) from WorkSheets" or something similar.  Your comment was helpful and I started googling for OLE Automation and found this link a really good start: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213621    As I was working through it "Head of Catering" answered the question completely, so I am pretty much good to go.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started. If you get stuck, post your code and explain what isn't working. **Test this first in a copy of your workbook** to prevent accidentally overwriting something you didn't mean to.

```
Sub HarvestAddresses()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    ' We will harvest all addresses onto the target sheet
    Set target = Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' First address will be copied to the target.Range, and subsequent addresses
    ' get copied to the cells below
    Set rng = target.Range("A1")
    i = 0

    ' We copy the value from "C8" in every worksheet in our workbook
    ' to the target
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        rng.Offset(i) = ws.Range("C8")
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```